# requestLocationUpdates not working from a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, location

Hi I'm trying to requestLocationUpdates from a Thread other than the UI Thread, I'm getting a RuntimeExeption in the following line:

```
// request location updates using Cellular 
lm.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
    0,
    0,
    locationListener);
```

Then reading the documentation it says that it Throws:

```
IllegalArgumentException  if provider is null or doesn't exist on this device 
IllegalArgumentException  if listener is null 
RuntimeException  if the calling thread has no Looper 
SecurityException  if no suitable permission is present
```

So it seems to be that my thread has no Looper, but the problem is that I don't know what they mean by a "Looper". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Change your `run()` code to

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    Looper.prepare();

    // The rest of your code

    Looper.loop();
}
```

Comment: Should I use the Looper on the whole run() method or only surround that specific line? Thanks!

Comment: Put it on the whole run() method as I have above. Should make no difference.

Comment: I know it's prehistoric, but adding Looper.loop(); did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

U can try this :

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
    0,
    0,
    locationListener,
    Looper.myLooper()
);
```